# How can I create a code/loop to automate the creation of a variable?

Tags: r, algorithm, loops

I am writing my thesis and I am struggling with some data preparation.

I have a dataset with `prices`, `distance`, and many other variables for several us airline routes. I need to identify the threat of entry on each route for a specific carrier (southwest) and to do that I need to create, for each row of the dataset, a dummy that assumes the value of 1 if southwest is flying from the takeoff airport of the row at that point in time.

How I thought of approaching this was to have an algorithm that checks the `year` and the takeoff `airport_ID` (all variables in the dataset) and then based on that values filter through all the dataset by `year` =< year row, `origin_airport`= origin_airport row, `carrier` = southwest. If the filter produces an output, it means that southwest is by that time already flying from that airport. Hence, if the filtering produces an output, the dummy should assume a value of 1, otherwise 0. This should be automated for each row in the dataset.

Any idea how to put this into Rstudio code? Or is there an easier way to address this issue?

This is the link to the dataset on dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n09rp2vcyqfx02r/DB1B_completeDB1B_complete.csv?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide  a representative subset of your data? Or a link to the full  dataset.

Comment: It is a personal dataset I have created myself. Which is the best to share it here? Sorry I am new :)

Comment: Can you put in on Dropbox and provide a link?

Comment: Does the link work?

Comment: @FedericoPuglisi Yes the link works. I'll look at it tonight.

Comment: I need to check the price reaction of incumbents to new entrants. So I will ultimately need time dummies for up until 8 quarters before the threat of entry starts, between the threat starts and the actually service on the route starts, and then for 8  quarters after the service on the route starts. I will then create a differences in differences model to check how the price reaction evolve in the period. And since the threat of entry is identified as "when a carrier flyes from two airports without connecting the two" I need for each obs to know if Southwest is present in both airport

Comment: Then, if it is, the variable threat_entry will assume a value of 1

Comment: Do you mean something like `DF$threat_entry <- as.numeric(with(DF, carrier == "southwest" & year <= 2010 & origin_airport == "SOMETHING"))` after importing the data by `DF <- read.csv("filename.csv")` or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use a self join.

Looking at your data set, I don't see IATA airport codes, but rather 6-digit origin and destination id's (which do not seem to conform to anything in DB1A/DB1B??). Also, it's not clear (to me) what exactly is the granularity of your data, so making some assumptions.

```
library(data.table)
setwd('<directory with your csv file>')
data <- fread('DB1B_completeDB1B_complete.csv')
wn   <- data[carrier=='WN']
data[,   flag:=0]
data[wn, flag:=1, on=.(ap_id, year, quarter, date)]
```

So, this just extracts the WN records and then joins that back to the original table, on `ap_id` (defines route??), `year`, `quarter`, and `date`. This assumes granularity is at the carrier/route/year/quarter/date level (e.g. one row per).

Before you do that, though, you need to do some serious data cleaning. For instance, while it looks like ORIGIN_AIRPORT_CD and DEST_AIRPORT_CD are parsed out of ap_id, there are about 1200 records where these are NA.

```
##
#   missingness
#
data[, .(col = names(data), na.count=sapply(.SD, \(x) sum(is.na(x))))]
```

Also, my assumption that there is one row per carrier/route/year/quarter/date does not seem to hold always. This is an especially serious problem wit the WN rows.

```
##
#   duplicates??
#
data[, .N, keyby=.(carrier, ap_id, year, quarter, date)][order(-N)]
wn[,   .N, keyby=.(carrier, ap_id, year, quarter, date)][order(-N)]
```

Finally, in attempting to quantify the impact of WN entry to a market, you probably should at least consider grouping nearby airports. For instance JFK/LGA/EWR are frequently considered "NYC", and SFO/OAK/SJC are frequently considered "Bay Area" (these are just examples). This means, for instance, that if WN started flying from LGA to a destination of interest it might also influence OA prices from JFK and EWR to that same destination.